# OS X App - Scroll View

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

I have a bunch of things in a scrollview but I cannot get the scrollview to scroll.

In iOS it is simple, we just need to put a view in the scrollview and then size the view to the dimensions we want to scroll. But in OS X, it isn't working. It is bouncing and resizing, but it is not scrolling. What am I missing?

I have a scroll view and within in that a clip view and within in that an NSview with a lot of elements. It just does not scroll. What do I need to set in storyboard to get it to scroll? Right now, I don't think I have set a height for the view to scroll. How do I do that? It does not let me set the height for the clip view. When I set the height for the NSView, it still does not scroll. It could also be an issue with the size of my window or how I setup the VC view controller. What are the best practices for sizing the window or the view controller? Any help would be really helpful. Or if you know any tutorials or places where I can get more info on this.